# display a text in a view and edit it

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've added a view to my plugin and I want to first, read and display a file content and second, have the possibility to modify the content . In other words I want to have an editable zone in my view , a sort of an editor . I didn't know what steps to follow to implement my class .
here is the class :

```
public class LabelView extends ViewPart {
 private Label label;


 public LabelView() {
  super();
 }

 public void setFocus() {
  label.setFocus();
 }

 public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  label = new Label(parent, 0);
 }
}
```

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Text](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html) object in the parent composite would be the simplest way.